# $F$ is heavy-tailed if and only if $\overline F$ is heavy-tailed

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $F$ be a distribution function on $\mathbb R_+$.

How can I show the following equivalence?

$F$ is heavy-tailed $\Leftrightarrow$ $\overline F=1-F$ is heavy-tailed

We call $F$ heavy-tailed if $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{tx}dF(x)=\infty,\quad \forall t>0.$$

We call a function $f$ heavy tailed $:\Leftrightarrow$ $\limsup_{x\to \infty}f(x)e^{tx}=\infty, \forall t>0$.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. I think the integral has a typo. 2. Are we assuming $F$ has a density? 3. What is $\overline{F}$ supposed to represent? It is not a distribution function because it is decreasing.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks, there were some mistakes. I corrected them. For $\overline F$ we use the 2nd definition. I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: @angryavian for $\overline F$